# Socket REST Augmentation

Tags: sockets, rest

Due to the proliferation of REST support and the new buzz around Websocket, there seems to be confusion around these two. Socket is a stateful communication fabric whereas REST is a stateless communication architecture. As far as I am concerned, these two are not in competition with one another and can be used in a complementary fashion.

What ways are there to use these two technologies together, such as creating a stateless communication architecture within a stateful communication fabric? How does using socket to call REST (GET, POST) improvement client-server communication?

An example of this is using live speech to text by IBM - https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/sample.shtml

Why is there a need to use sockets at all? Why isn't is possible to just perform GETs on partial answers using the same session ID?